# Require() php error when trying to include files

Tags: php, sql

Hi I'm currently trying to include some functions in a PHP script but keep getting an error that I'm really struggling to figure out. I've gone through permissions and a few other things but to no avail.

Here's my php - the code within it is just to test a few things and I don't  think that its not effecting the 'require()' call, but I maybe wrong obviously.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require(__DIR__ . "/../includes/config.php");

if ($argc !=2)
{
    print("Please specify file path \n");
    return -1;
}

$file = $argv[1];
print($file);

if (!file_exists($file))
    {
        print("Error: file " . $file . " doesn't exist\n");
        //return -1;  
    } 

if (is_writable($file)) 
    {
        $copy = 'copy1.txt';

        $handle = file_get_contents($file);

        file_put_contents($copy, $handle);

    } 

else 
    {
        echo "The file $filename is not writable \n";
    }
end;

$test = query("INSERT INTO  `pset8`.`places` (
        `id` ,
        `country_code` ,
        `postal_code` ,
        `place_name` ,
        `admin_name1` ,
        `admin_code1` ,
        `admin_name2` ,
        `admin_code2` ,
        `admin_name3` ,
        `admin_code3` ,
        `latitude` ,
        `longitude` ,
        `accuracy`
        )
        VALUES (
        '2',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  ''
        )");

?>
```

And here is the error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(../vendor/library50-php-5/CS50/CS50.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/includes/config.php on line 20
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/bin/import:0
PHP   2. require() /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/bin/import:3

Warning: require(../vendor/library50-php-5/CS50/CS50.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/includes/config.php on line 20

Call Stack:
    0.0002     235656   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/bin/import:0
    0.0022     238328   2. require('/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/includes/config.php') /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/bin/import:3

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../vendor/library50-php-5/CS50/CS50.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/includes/config.php on line 20
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/bin/import:0
PHP   2. require() /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/bin/import:3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../vendor/library50-php-5/CS50/CS50.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/includes/config.php on line 20

Call Stack:
    0.0002     235656   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/bin/import:0
    0.0022     238328   2. require('/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/includes/config.php') /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/bin/import:3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the folder-structure look like? Where is the folder `vendor` in relation to `includes`?

Comment: Essentially the file structure has been pre set up as part of a pset for CS50. The vendor folder is on the same level as includes and has the same parent - pset8.  It is set up on a cloud9 IDE. Hope that helps?

Comment: From what I can read off the errors, they occur when trying to access the `config.php` script, and you try to include the file `CS50.php` - is this correct?

Comment: I try to include config.php and then config.php asks for several other items such as 'query' which is in CS50.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not a permissions-issue, it's a matter of including files from the correct paths. From what I can read off your errors, and from what you stated in comments, your `includes`/`requires` seems to be including from the wrong paths.

Accodring to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), `__DIR__` returns the path of the current file. As an example, your `config.php` file would return `/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/includes`.

When you now use `/../` at the end when including (ex: `include __DIR."/../";`), that means to go up a folder, ending on the path `/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8`. You can do this multiple times (ex: `include __DIR."/../../";` will end on `/home/ubuntu/workspace`).

So basically, you'll need to know where you are at all times, and include from that. You could also hard-code it (so that you `include "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8/includes/config.php";`), but I would suggest a more dynamic approach (should you end up using a different host, then you just change a few lines instead of many).

You could define a variable that you include from, something like

```
define("BASEFOLDER", "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset8");
require BASEFOLDER."/includes/config.php";
```

Note that you need to define `BASEFOLDER` for each file, it's not a global definition.